# How to contain an image in the division when browser zoom?

Tags: image, browser, background, zooming

I have an image in the header background which I cannot force to keep changing proportionally and being contained (and cover at the same time) in the header div while you zoom a browser. While zooming out it leaves empty margins on the sides

Please, have a look at live example http://sch180.minsk.edu.by/

The CSS code for the header div is the following:

```
body {
    width:100%;
    min-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    background:url(/sm.aspx?guid=1913);
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0px;
}
#hd {
    background: url(/sm.aspx?guid=1903) top center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

As I'm no expert in web design, surely I'm doing something wrong. Please, help me to rectify the code for the header.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried adding to `#hd { background-size:100% }` ?

Comment: Just tried. It does help to stick the sides. But while zooming out it cuts the height (the image from the bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution, in my opinion, would be to use an `img` tag instead of `background-image`.

For example:

```
<div id="hd"><img src="sm.aspx?guid=1903" /></div>

#hd img {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Dear Barnee, thx for trying to help out. I did like you said but only added 10% margins. However, now the image does not fit to the div and being duplicated. Plz have a look on the site.

Comment: Then you should change the `width` to `80%`.